# What is the difference between using `return` outside and inside of conditions?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

What is the difference between using `return` in outside of else condition and inside of else condition?

I know the best code is without use `else`  and I know both are doing similarly  same. Is there difference or advantages?

```js
       
         function f1() {
            if (1 == 1) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

function f2() {
            if (1 !== 1) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
            return false
        }
        
        console.log(f1());
        console.log(f2());
```

Comment: JavaScript is async in nature so you have to be carefull while returning the the response

Comment: Isn't that the same question as the one you linked to?

Comment: What tool produces that error and what is the **exact** error message?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I didn't get any error message.  the method 1 is return true/false in normal java script code. But it works different (return undefined)  in my attached link.

Comment: I guess the problem is the `// here i have some logic's.` you mentioned in the answer to the linked question.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Nope. Because when i remove the logic's and just tried with return true and false.  **Not Working**

Comment: I think this needs a way to reproduce like http://stackblitz.com

Comment: SaveVersionMainScreen() {
            return !this.commonValidation(true);
           
         }

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Okay. I have update my question. leave my previous question relations..

Comment: what is this? @RameshRajendran why you are changing your code completely? why just don't you expand question with updated code?

Comment: @ZaidMirza Because i need to the sample code in snippet. that's why i have removed my normal code and  i have move that code to snippet.

Comment: There is still no way to reproduce your issue. The `return false` outside `if/else` is redundant because it will never be executed. Both examples are equivalent except `!==` vs `==`.

Comment: @RameshRajendran you should not remove completely. you should enhance. On this post Three answers and many comments according to your old question. New searchers will get confused. Who will come here later for or to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Not related to your previous question, but only this:**

In Method:2, the last `return` statement (ie `return true;`) is virtually useless. Because last line in the `SaveVersionMainScreen()` won't be executed as there is `if` and `else` both conditions are present. Which should account for all cases.

Answer (score 1):

if you have  `if` statement within block code and contains `return` in both `if` and `else` block. Its mean either `if` block will execute and `return` from method or `else` block will execute and `return`. Other statements below that blocks will not execute and compiler may give you error something like

> Statements cannot be reached

For Example:

```
SaveVersionMainScreen() {
        let element = this.commonValidation(true);
        if (element) {            
            return false;
        }
        else{
          return true;
        }

// Below  statements will never run

          var a=2;
          var b=3;
          var c=4;
          return true;
         }
```

Comment: I don't get you.

Comment: Both methods are working same.I have checked  with snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Way to go changing you question completely. Leaving my answer anyway for now.
 Your version 2 is bad practice, code would not work in a strict language like Java as you have a return statement that cannot be reached. As for your test removing the else from your function should solve it for you, but the issueseems to be with the test and not your code.

```
SaveVersionMainScreen() {
    let element = this.commonValidation(true);
    if (element) {            
        return false;
    }
  return true;
 }
```